# print SQL output in jade file

Tags: sql, node.js, pug

I'm trying to output an sql query in Jade file. I got it so far that I can print plain text to jade but when I try to put an output from SQL it doesn't work can someone help me.

The code in app.js (NodeJS) :

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM user ', function(err, rows)
{
    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
    console.log('num of records is '+rows.length);
    //console.log(rows);

    res.render('index',
        { title : 'Home' }
    )
    res.render('index',
        { row : res.send(rows) }
    )
    console.log('num of records is '+rows.length);
});
```

The code in jade (What I have at the moment):

```
  - each row in rows
        p=row.first_names
```

Comment: Any errors or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call render once like this:

```
res.render('index', {
  title: 'Home',
  rows: rows
});
```

The single call contains the object with all of the values you want passed to the Jade template.  Also note the change of the key `row` to `rows` since that is what you called it in your template, as well as not calling `res.send` inside of `res.render`

Comment: This is not the problem I guess because I changed it but it still doesn't print any output in my page. (there is no output in my page )

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit .js file (app.js in this case). And also the jade file code seems not correct

```
res.render('index', {title:'Home', row:rows});
```

Then the jade code should be changed as following. Be sure to indent properly. 'first_names' is case-sensitive

```
ul
each val in row
 li=val.first_names
```

Reference: http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration